# Setting grid items to share columns and not overlap

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid, styled-components

I am making a day row in a calendar with many events. Some events might happen at the same time as others. If this is the case, I would like the events should share the width of the row.

How can this be done without setting an outer container? I don't want to set an outer container, because then I would need to loop through all events and group them.

Instead I would just like to give them props for the style to be like this:

```
grid-row: 10 / 14
```

I am using React so the simplified component for this example is like this:

```
const Slots = styled.div`
    background: #eee;
    height: calc(100vh - 35px);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(48, auto [slot]);
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-gap: 0px 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
`;

const Event = styled.div`
    background-color: ${props => props.color ? props.color : "yellow"};
    grid-row: ${props => props.start} / ${props => props.end};
    border-radius: 3px;
`;

export default () => {
    return (
        <Day index={1}>
            <Slots>
                <Event start={6} end={9}>An event at 06 am - 09 am</Event>
                <Event color="red" start={6} end={7}>An event at 06 am - 07 am</Event>
                <Event start={10} end={14}>An event at 10 am - 2 pm</Event>
            </Slots>
        </Day>
    )
}
```

Currently this is the result for events at the same rows:

[image]

Comment: Nope, I'm pretty sure you need to wrap the events for a day in a container. Items with the same grid-cell values will overlap...thats by design.

Comment: @Paulie_D That really is a bummer. How can this be done in reality? I can have an event taking up the whole day that starts in a half an hour slot. That would overlap all later slots anyway?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that this is too complex for CSS without breaking the days into a grid with multiple columns that would accept events.

Comment: Something like this - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/YzPdMox